# ERROR:PDO Exception could not find driver, while installing laravel hackathon starter kit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5

I have used [this](https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-hackathon-starter/issues) laravel starter kit and followed steps as mentioned. Everthing goes well, however while running `php artisan migrate`, I have got this error `PDO Exception could not find driver`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What driver? Have you configured one?

Comment: @ tadman no idea about the driver.. thats the problem actually, if the name was mentioned I would have searched for that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?